# How to pass parameters to a "Job as Task" from code?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, scheduled-tasks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

I would like to use the new "Job as Task" feature (as mentioned [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76882615/219344)) but I'm having trouble to pass values into that job.

**Scenario**

- I have a workflow job which contains 2 tasks.
- The workflow is scheduled to run every x minutes.
- **Task_A** (type "Notebook"): Read data from a table and based on the contents decide, whether the workflow in Task_B should be executed (or not).
- **Task_B** (type "Run Job"): This references another Workflow that itself consists of multiple tasks, all of type "Notebook". The workflow takes several parameters. For the sake of brevity here, let's just assume a parameter `entity_ids`. This workflow runs totally fine on its own if started manually.

For this scenario I would like to add some logic that decides how much of the workflow will be executed:

If Task_A finds specific information in its table, it should start the workflow in Task_B and provide it with a couple of parameters based on that information (in this example: a list of `entity_ids`). If that information is not found, the workflow should end gracefully and wait for the next interval.

**My question:
How do I pass (multiple) values into the job that is referenced in Task_B?**

I had tried to set this with `dbutils.jobs.taskValues.set("entity_id", "[1, 2]")` in Task_A and read with `dbutils.jobs.taskValues.get("Task_A", "entity_ids", debugValue="[]" )` in the first Notebook of the workflow in Task_B, but this throws an error within the nested job:
`Task key does not exist in run: Task_A.`

My guess is that the nested workflow in Task_B is unaware of the parent workflow and might be run in a different context, and therefore cannot find `taskKey == "Task_A"`.

To verify my assumption, I tried setting up a (test-only) Notebook that only reads the `entity_ids`with the `get()` function.

- If I add it directly as a task, into the same workflow as Task_A, it works.
- If I put it into its own workflow, and then reference that as a "Run Job" task, it fails with the aforementioned error.

In both cases, it is always the exact same Notebook.

Comment: I tried and can confirm that the behaviour is as you said. Would this alternative work ? In your **Task_B (type "Run Job")** create a widget named `entity_id`, and then in the Run Job task pass the task value `({{tasks.Task_A.values.entity_ids}})` to the widget as parameter. I can confirm that this works.

Comment: Also for your conditional, you can use a if then else block and use the task value. For testing I tried using `{{tasks.Tst_TaskVal_Set.values.entity_id}} != ""` and then trigger the Run Job only if it is empty. Click on Dynamic Values for format and other values.

Comment: But considering your number of parameters, see if you an set a flag as task value, write entity_ids to a file and the use the conditionals on the task value flag, and then read the file in the Task B - Also maybe there is a limit on the number of characters that the task value can accept ? - I am not sure

Comment: @rainingdistros, thank you very much for your suggestions! I'll have a try at them today and get back to you.

Comment: @rainingdistros, that totally helped! I now have my workflow running with both parameters AND condition. As your suggestions were the first - and more complete- I would accept them as solution (if you wanted to re-post them as answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your approach and can confirm that the behaviour of task variable when used in a "Run Job" Task is as you said.

Please check if the following alternative would work for you ?

- In your `Task_B` (type "Run Job"), create a widget named `entity_id`
- In your actual workflow, following `Task_A`, add a `if then else` block with a check on the task value. Refer to [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/workflows/jobs/conditional-tasks.html#add-branching-logic-to-your-job-with-the-ifelse-condition-task) for further information.

  - For testing I tried using {{tasks.Tst_TaskVal_Set.values.entity_id}} != "" and then trigger the Run Job only if it is empty. You can click on Dynamic Values for format and other similar values.
- The truth flow can be followed by the `Run Job` task where you can pass the task value `{{tasks.Task_A.values.entity_ids}}` to the widget as a parameter. I can confirm that this works.

Alternate Suggestion:

But considering your number of parameters, see if you can set a flag as task value, write entity_ids to a file in DBFS or cloud and the use the conditionals on the task value flag, and then read the file in the Task_B - Also there may be a limit on the number of characters that the task value/widget can accept.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot obtain task values set in one task in a following task of type **Run Job**. To get these values, you need to pass them as parameters using dynamic values and access them using the code below in your notebook, which is in another workflow job.

```
dbutils.widgets.get("entity_id")
```

[image]

Click on **Browse dynamic values** for more information.

`{{tasks.[task_name].values.[value_name]}}` is the dynamic expression for obtaining task values for a specific task and given key.

In your case, it is `{{tasks.Task_A.values.entity_id}}`

Output:

[image]

Here, **B_tasks** is another job.

Comment: Thank you very much, @JayashankarGS! The screenshots helped me a great deal, too.